# How to frame this data science problem to have ML algorithm optimize input function?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have data generated using production machine. Different components of these machine have certain initial vague functions assigned to them through which we maintain response of this machine.

For example

component 1 = function f1 (could be temperature)
component 2 = function f2 (could be pressure)
.
.
.
.
and it continues till f20.

All these functions have priorities which are maintained in the graph, which is followed for production machine's actions.

For example, f1 (temperature should not exceed 100 degrees) has more priority than f2 (pressure should not exceed certain threshold). If f1 is achieved, machine should stop working to prevent damage but if f2 is reached, machine does not need to be stopped but speed of production should be reduced.

Is there any good way to frame this approach where I can update and optimize these functions and their priorities, assigned to these components using data generated through these components? Can you let me know if there could be something missing here which can not achieve this goal or may be better way to frame this problem?